# QT - Lambda-Capture by reference - qmlRegisterSingletonType

Tags: c++, qt, qml

main.cpp:

```
MyClass *myclass = new MyClass();
MyClassMember *member = myclass->member;

int myclassmember_id= qmlRegisterSingletonType<MyClassMember>("medica.singleton", 1, 0, "MyClassMember", [&member](QQmlEngine *engine, QJSEngine *scriptEngine) -> QObject * {
    ...
}
```

Qt does not allow me to capture by reference and signs the "[&member]" part as an error, saying: "no matching function for call to 'qmlRegisterSingletonType'".

I also tried to do this in my main.cpp:

```
MyClass *myclass = new MyClass();
int myclassmember_id= qmlRegisterSingletonType<MyClassMember>("medica.singleton", 1, 0, "MyClassMember", [](QQmlEngine *engine, QJSEngine *scriptEngine) -> QObject * {
    MyClassMember *member = myclass->member;
    ...
}
```

But Qt says variable 'member' cannot be implicitly captured in a lambda with no capture-default specified.

How can I use "member" by reference inside my lambda expression?

MINIMAL REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE: myclass.h:

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

#include "myclassmember.h"

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();
    MyClassMember *member;
};

#endif // MYCLASS_H
```

myclass.cpp:

```
#include "myclass.h"

MyClass::MyClass()
{
    member = new MyClassMember();
}
```

myclassmember.h:

```
#ifndef MYCLASSMEMBER_H
#define MYCLASSMEMBER_H

#include <QList>


class MyClassMember
{
public:
    MyClassMember();
    QList<int> mylist;

    void addNumber(int _num);
};

#endif // MYCLASSMEMBER_H
```

myclassmember.cpp:

```
#include "myclassmember.h"

MyClassMember::MyClassMember()
{

}

void MyClassMember::addNumber(int _num)
{
    mylist.append(_num);
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

#include "myclass.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    MyClass *myclass = new MyClass();
    MyClassMember *member = myclass->member;

    int uibackend_id = qmlRegisterSingletonType<MyClassMember>("medica.singleton", 1, 0, "MyClassMember", [](QQmlEngine *engine, QJSEngine *scriptEngine) -> QObject * {
        Q_UNUSED(engine)
        Q_UNUSED(scriptEngine)

            member->addNumber(1); //ERROR: variable 'member' cannot be implicitly captured in a lambda with no capture-default specified

    });

    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: change to  `"MyClassMember", [myclass](QQmlEngine *engine`

Comment: @eyllanesc still get the qt error "no matching function for call to qmlRegisterSingletonType

Comment: `"MyClassMember", [&member](QQmlEngine *engine` is different to `"MyClassMember", [myclass](QQmlEngine *engine`

Comment: @eyllanesc it is, but the error I get by correcting the code as you suggest, is "no matching function for call to qmlRegisterSingletonType"

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc provided!

Comment: Your example compiles fine (after deriving MyClassMember from QObject) when the `member` variable is passed by copy or by reference (even by copy might be dangerous since in your real world application the local var goes out of scope)

Comment: @chehrlic the example does not compile fine to me by deriving MyClassMember from QObject and by adding the "&" as follows... where am I making the mistake?? int uibackend_id = qmlRegisterSingletonType<MyClassMember>("medica.singleton", 1, 0, "MyClassMember", [&](QQmlEngine *engine, QJSEngine *scriptEngine) -> QObject * {

Comment: You could also change it to be a rootContext property if things don't compile (for which I suspect a different version of c++/compiler/qt)

Answer (score 1):

It has 2 errors:

- You have to pass member in the captures section.

  ```cpp
  int uibackend_id = qmlRegisterSingletonType<MyClassMember>("medica.singleton", 1, 0, "MyClassMember",
                                                             [member](QQmlEngine *engine, QJSEngine *scriptEngine) -> QObject * {
          Q_UNUSED(engine)
          Q_UNUSED(scriptEngine)
          member->addNumber(1);
          return member;
  });
  ```
- Only QObjects can be singleton.

  ```cpp
  class MyClassMember: public QObject
  {
      // ...
  };
  ```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to eyllanesc's answer.. Qt 5.12 will not compile a lambda with a closure in `qmlRegisterSingletonType` while Qt 5.15 will.